# Spring Kafka Consumer printing incorrect headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Boot's `KafkaListener` to consume events from a Kafka topic. I am interested in reading the headers for the events. I am able to get the correct value of individual headers when I read them individually but when I try to read it as a map, the values seem different.

This is what my code looks like:

```
public final class KafkaConsumer {

  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "#{'${event.consumer.topics}'.split(',')}",
      groupId = "${event.consumer.groupId}",
      containerFactory = "kafkaListenerFactory")
  public void receive(
      ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord,
      @Header("foo") String foo,
      @Headers Map<String, String> header,
      Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

    try {
      System.out.println(foo);
      System.out.println(header.get("foo");
      acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The first print statement gives the correct value (bar) but the second statement prints some garbage ([B@5f1af89d). Can someone let me know how to read the headers correctly as a map?

Answer (score 2):

`[B@5f1af89d` is the result of `toString()` on a `byte[]`. Headers sent over Kafka are `byte[]`. Use `new String(header.get("foo"))`.

That said, the `id` header is a `UUID`, not `byte[]`, and it is created locally so there is something amiss in your question. You say you are sending header `foo` but you are printing `id`.

Answer (score 0):

That garbage looks to me just like the output of 'toString' from an Object that does not provide an implementation, or from an Array type.

I'd suggest taking a look at the header object in a Debugger to understand what's going on.  It might need to be declared as <String, Object> or something.  This exercise should also help you know if your producer is doing the right thing or not.

Comment: I tried that & I could see the value coming as a String object. Also tried with a Java producer & a kafkacat producer but I still see the issue

Comment: Is the Producer sending a String type for the id header's value?

Comment: Yes. This is the command that I am using
echo 'mypayload' |kafkacat -P -b localhost:9092 -t test -H "id=foo"